# using simpletip but it sends me on error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, simpletip

i really need some help guys im trying to use the simpletip but it send me on error [error that sends me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qh2a.png) my image is on carpet named imagenes and inside that carpet is another carpet named refacciones and there is were my images are (imagenes/refacciones/image.png) i think thats that problem but i don't now how to fix it on my database i have a table named refacciones inside that table i have a column name imagen were a save thte src of the images

```
<?php
<define('INCLUDE_CHECK',1);
require "../conexion.php";

if(!$_POST['img']) die("NO product exist!");

$img=mysql_real_escape_string(end(explode('/',$_POST['img'])));

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM refacciones WHERE imagen='".$img."'"));

if(!$row) die("NO product exist!");

echo '<strong>'.$row['nombre'].'</strong>
<span>Ficha Tecnica</span>
<p class="modelo">Modelo:'.$row['modelo'].'</p>
<p class="marca">Marca:'.$row['marca'].'</p>
<p class="descr">Descripcion:'.$row['descripcion'].'</p>

<strong>precio: $'.$row['precio'].'</strong>
<small>Arrastralo a la sección de cotización.</small>';
?>
```

I realy would i preciate your help

Comment: try the process in separate ways like this: 
`$img = explode('/',$_POST['img']);
$img = end($img);
$img=mysql_real_escape_string($img);`

Comment: thank you for answering i try it and it doesn´t send me none of errors it only sends me saying that the product doesn't exist but i do have the image on my carpet and on my data base has some data of the product.